# Unable to add logo in wordpress website. The customize > header > add logo is not available in website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[This is the front page of my website, here you can see logo is not showing at top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnd9g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear if your theme includes a place for a logo in the template, so I would start by looking at the theme's documentation to see if its included.

If not, other options include creating a child theme to extend the functionality of the parent theme (the one you're currently using), or editing your theme directly (this is not generally recommended as changes will be lost if updated).

Here's the documentation on child-themes: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

You'll need to locate the template to know where to make changes. Wordpress does a pretty good job of documenting that process as well.

Comment: I want to make changes in the existing theme, can you help me to find a code snippet or provide one, or may be a plugin that will do the task

Comment: Im doing someones else website, and do not have cpanel credentials, All I can do is make changes in wp-admin

Comment: You should first find the name of the theme, and see if its included out of the box first. Making theme changes through the WP admin is considered bad practice. Second, I would see if it can be achieved through the wysiwyg editor on the page edit screen by placing your image tag & positioning it with inline css (again, this is not a great way to achieve your aim, just a way that's possible). At least this way you're not changing theme core. If all else fails, you can edit the files through the admin, just be warned that if you upgrade you will lose your changes.

Comment: ok I got it, theme name: the7, by default theme has a logo, but after the developer made changes according to the client, the logo was might be delected from the code, and I from the other end of the world is giver the task to ass the logo

Comment: can you please more elaborate or give me a link of some tutorial to add the logo

Comment: I am now doing something else, it is a woocommerce product, whenever I upload the image in product, it does not fix in the div, image stretched and not shown perfectly

Comment: Open a new question, as this is not related. I'd appreciate if you accept my answer if it worked for you. Thanks!